# How to take all values from SQL table column on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to select all column values irrespective of NULL as column value.

My problem is when I try to select values using IS NULL I'm getting such records also these having NULL as a value.

```
declare @status varchar(50)=NULL
declare @path varchar(50)= 'India'

select 
*
from [vwMYDATA] 
where
Path like '%' + @path + '%' and
(Status = @status or @status IS NULL)
```

vwMYDATA

```
path    status
INDIA1  NULL  
INDIA2  close
INDIA3  open
```

If I execute above query I'm getting all records whose status column has NULL value. Expected is if no status value specified show all status records:

```
path    status
INDIA1  NULL  
INDIA2  close
INDIA3  open
```

It is showing:

```
path    status
INDIA1  NULL
```

I'm passing these 2 parameters to stored procedure which is having this select statement.

How can I filter out and show all the records if status is not given as input?

Comment: Please also include the part where `@status` is supposed to change, I think we need that bit more context

Comment: I'm passing these parameters to stored proce which will execute above select staement

Comment: how about if else block if `@status` is null return all with path selected only otherwise use your current where condition..

Comment: Are you saying that if you pass INDIA1 and null to your procedure, you expect to receive back all 3 records?

Comment: @DanBracuk exactly it should show me all 3 records
(actually there should not be an NULL in status but now it is there in database so I have to work on that)

Comment: Change your stored procedure to SELECT @status instead of anything else, and you can use that to check your parameters are what you think they are.

Comment: You most likely have a typo in your where, the query you currently have there will return all 3 rows. If you change where to (Status = @status or status IS NULL) then you will only get the null row.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your query, [This example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c63ef/1) shows it working as you have described you want. If you pass `NULL` as the value for @Status you get all results.However I would strongly advise against this approach, use an `IF/ELSE` block in your procedure for reasons explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18697104/1048425), and in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18655582/1048425)

Comment: @GarethD if else could be the best option but i have more than 7 fields options so, so many if else thats why i'm finding the better way :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
*
from [vwMYDATA] 
where
Path like '%' + @path + '%' and
((@status IS NULL )OR (Status = @status or status IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the WHERE clause to a Case statement if you want different actions based on whether the @status varchar is NULL.

```
Select *
From [vwMYDATA]
Where
    Path Like Concat('%', @path, '%') And
    1 = (
        Case When @status Is Null Then 1
        When Status = @status Then 1
        Else 0
    )
```

This might be inefficient and nonperformant. For performance, it would be better to have a completely different query that matches based on NULL or not, so that proper indexing can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to always filter out records with a null status (which it seems you are) then this should work:

```
declare @status varchar(50)=NULL
declare @path varchar(50)= 'India'

select 
*
from [vwMYDATA] 
where
Path like '%' + @path + '%' and
(Status = @status or @status IS NULL)
AND Status IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try remove `or @status IS NULL` condition

```
select 
*
from [vwMYDATA] 
where
Path like '%' + @path + '%' and
(Status = @status)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your condition like below:

```
declare @status varchar(50)=NULL
declare @path varchar(50)= 'India'

select 
*
from [vwMYDATA] 
where
Path like '%' + @path + '%' and
(@status IS NULL OR Status = @status)
```

you just need to change the place of condition because the conditions check from first, so now if the @status will be null, query don't check next condition.

Comment: This is not true. The order of the predicates is not relevant, SQL-Server will evaluate them in whatever order it deems to be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Get NUll Value Records on Status
select * from vwMYDATA where status is null

Get Not NUll Value Records on Status
select * from vwMYDATA where status is not null

Comment: Try to express yourself. Brief answers like this one are most likely to be useless for original poster and community.