# SELECT WHERE some text, contains square brackets

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have some text column, that have format like

```
 ["some text", ]
```

Let this column has name col1. And do

```
SELECT columname FROM table WHERE col1 = '["some text", ]'
```

I receive nothing. But with

```
SELECT columname FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '["some text", ]'
```

I receive needed data. I really don't understand why is it so. I want to use **=**, 'cos I read a lot that **LIKE** is much slower. And also I really don't understand why is it so.

**UPD:**
As requested more info

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fulldata (col1 TEXT, data TEXT);
```

Insert I do via QSqlQuery with prepare

```
insertData.prepare("INSERT INTO fulldata(col1 , data) "
                      " VALUES(:col1, :data);");
insertData.bindValue(":col1", currentFilter);
```

currentFilter is *[ "2014-01-14 00:00:00", 2 ]*

Select I also do using QSqlQuery with prepare

```
  selectQuery.prepare("SELECT data FROM fulldata WHERE col1 = :col1 ");
  selectQuery.bindValue(":col1 ", strFilter);
```

strFilter is also *[ "2014-01-14 00:00:00", 2 ]*

Also I do select from "Qt SQL Browser" from Qt 5.1 examples, same result as from code.

My **SQLite version = 3.7.17**

Comment: It is strange that you get different results. However, there is really no point in using LIKE without wildcards (i.e. % sign), but if you do the speed should be similar, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404226/sql-like-with-no-wildcards-the-same-as

Comment: Any leading/trailing whitespace or similar in either bindvalue that would make the binary collator to not match?

Comment: @laalto no, I double-checked that..

Answer (score 0):

Both are returning correct results.

Check here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4c033/4

I assume you're missing something else, just some detail which you did not mention in the question.

Yes, `LIKE` is indeed much slower.

**EDIT:**

Tried it on my local machine, still no issues.

[image]

Comment: Of course my real tables called in other way. Indeed on your link both variant works. I use SQLite 3, and there I got behavior described in the question

Comment: @user3136871 That is really weird. Answer updated. Maybe you should update your question with the exact statements you have for 1) table creation; 2) data insertion; 3) data selection. I think it is some detail which you're missing and which is not mentioned in the question.