# How can I query Rails ActiveRecord data stored in arrays

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails model call MentorData and it has an attribute called `os_usage`. The oses are stored in an array like so `['apple',  'linux']`.

To recap:

```
$ MentorData.first.os_usage
=> ['apple',  'linux']
```

I am looking to be able to query the data for all MentorData that includes the os_usage of `apple`, but when I search `MentorData.where(os_usage: 'apple')` I only get the mentors who can only use apple and not apple and linux. I need to search in some way that checks if apple is included in the array.

I have also tried the following.

```
MentorData.where('os_usage like ?', 'apple’)
MentorData.where('os_usage contains ?', 'apple’)
MentorData.where('os_usage contains @>ARRAY[?]', 'apple')
```

Is it possible to query data in ActiveRecord by attributes that have an array or items?

The database is on Postgres if that helps in providing a more raw search query.

Comment: The Rails Guides tell you how to do this, and many more PostgreSQL-specific operations: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here are the examples given in the current [Rails Edge Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) for PostgreSQL:

```
# db/migrate/20140207133952_create_books.rb
create_table :books do |t|
  t.string 'title'
  t.string 'tags', array: true
  t.integer 'ratings', array: true
end
add_index :books, :tags, using: 'gin'
add_index :books, :ratings, using: 'gin'
 
# app/models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
end
 
# Usage
Book.create title: "Brave New World",
            tags: ["fantasy", "fiction"],
            ratings: [4, 5]
 
## Books for a single tag
Book.where("'fantasy' = ANY (tags)")
 
## Books for multiple tags
Book.where("tags @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ["fantasy", "fiction"])
 
## Books with 3 or more ratings
Book.where("array_length(ratings, 1) >= 3")
```

Comment: What if I want to check value is blank array? Like `[]`

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `MentorData.where("'apple' = ANY (os_usage)")`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should detach the `os_usage` array from your model and make it a separate table.

In ActiveRecord world you will get something like the following code:

```
class MentorData < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  has_and_belongs_to_many :os_usage
  ..
end

class OsUsage < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  has_and_belongs_to_many :mentors_data
  ..
end
```

Creating a `many_to_many` relationship between this two models, allows you to query easily and avoid duplications. This technique is called *normalization*.

Using this new *design* you have your collection of **os_usage** made by objects instead of *strings*

```
MentorData.first.os_usage
# => [#<OsUsage:....>, #<OsUsage:...>]
```

Which you can convert easy into the old array of strings

```
MentorData.first.os_usage.map(&:name)
# => ['apple',  'linux']
```

In addition, you can query the data for all MentorData that includes the os_usage of *apple*:

```
MentorData.joins(:os_usages).where('os_usages.name' => 'apple')
```

And also query all the MentorData records for an OsUsage:

```
OsUsage.where(name: 'apple').mentors_data
```

I hope you find it useful :)

Comment: This is a great write up and makes a lot of sense. It seems like a better approach than my current.

Answer (score 0):

For like queries, you need %% to indicate that text can appear on the left or right of your search.

So, try

`MentorData.where('os_usage LIKE "%apple%"')`

and see if that works.

It is a wild card search, but omitting the % operates like =

See this question: [SQL LIKE with no wildcards the same as '='?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404226/sql-like-with-no-wildcards-the-same-as)

This assumes `os_usage` is a serialized array, where the column backing that data is a string, and rails deserializes when instantiating your `MentorData`

Edit: I'd find out how your db is storing the array, so maybe you could do

```
"%'apple'%"
```

to make sure that it doesn't select oses with apple just contained in the name.

Comment: I had to make a change, but `%`'s worked. MentorData.where('os_usage LIKE ?', "%apple%")

Comment: Another note: ActiveRecord actually makes the array a string, which is why this works

Comment: @mu is too short, sorry. I made the assumption that os_usage is a serialized column, stored as a string, and then deserialized back in to an array.

brianllamar, glad it worked :-)

Comment: This is not a perfect answer. For the sake of the example, imagine a new OS called "IN OS" gets released and is named `in` in your database.

Then when you search for records containing `in`, you'll write the query `MentorData.where('os_usage LIKE "%in%"')` and also grab all records that contain `linux` and `windows`, although they might not contain `in` as in "IN OS".